# C# Rest API error: "Missing key, signature and nonce parameters" for Bitstamp. I did include them in the code.. what could be wrong?

Tags: c#, api, authentication, nonce

So the title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to make a POST request to this API: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/

I'm also adding all correct headers called X-Auth, as instructed here: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/

But when I then execute the code, it's telling me that I'm missing the key, signature and nonce parameters. When I debug, I do see them in the list. So I really don't understand why I am still getting this error. Can someone look inside the code and help me out, please?

Kind regards! 
Here is the code:

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        private readonly String _clientId = "xxx";
        private readonly String _apiKey = "xxx";
        private readonly String _apiSecret = "xxx";

        static void Main()
        {
            Program program = new Program();

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/api/v2/balance/", Method.POST);

            program.AddApiAuthentication(request);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void AddApiAuthentication(RestRequest restRequest)
        {
            var nonce = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            var signature = GetSignature(nonce, _apiKey, _apiSecret, _clientId);
            long time = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            string version = "v2";
            string contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            restRequest.AddParameter("X-Auth", _apiKey);
            restRequest.AddParameter("X-Auth-Signature", signature);
            restRequest.AddParameter("X-Auth-Nonce", nonce);
            restRequest.AddParameter("X-Auth-Timestamp", time);
            restRequest.AddParameter("X-Auth-Version", version);
            restRequest.AddParameter("Content-Type", contentType);


            RestClient client = new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = new Uri("https://www.bitstamp.net/")
            };

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(restRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }

        private string GetSignature(long nonce, string key, string secret, string clientId)
        {
            string msg = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", nonce,
                clientId,
                key);

            return ByteArrayToString(SignHMACSHA256(secret, StringToByteArray(msg))).ToUpper();
        }
        public static byte[] SignHMACSHA256(String key, byte[] data)
        {
            HMACSHA256 hashMaker = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
            return hashMaker.ComputeHash(data);
        }

        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] hash)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm mostly guessing here, but if this is [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp), then your calls to [.AddParameter](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/src/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L342) should most likely be [.AddHeader](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/src/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L385).

Comment: That helped me a bunch, Lasse. Based on that, it started to give different errors and I worked through all of them. I now have a completely intact version here. Should I just post it here? Or make a new question that asks how to make a call to a private API for Bitstamp and then answer my own question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Lasse V. Karlsen told me, I could get it to work so that it no longer only displayed the API0000 error. I started getting other errors and with the help of a nice guy on the C# Discord channel I could work out a solution. I now have a completely working code here that will allow you to do private API calls using your API key. 
Here is the code:

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {

        private readonly string _apiKey = "BITSTAMP" + " " + "XXX";
        private readonly string _apiSecret = "XXX";
        private readonly string _URL = "www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/";
        private readonly string _queryParam = "";
        private readonly string _contentType = "";
        private readonly string _payloadString = "";

        static void Main()
        {
            Program program = new Program();

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/v2/balance/", Method.POST);

            program.AddApiAuthentication(request);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void AddApiAuthentication(RestRequest restRequest)
        {
            var nonce = Guid.NewGuid();
            var timer = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(timer);
            string version = "v2";
            var signature = GetSignature(nonce, _apiKey, _apiSecret, timer);
            restRequest.AddHeader("X-Auth", _apiKey);
            restRequest.AddHeader("X-Auth-Signature", signature);
            restRequest.AddHeader("X-Auth-Nonce", nonce.ToString()); ;
            restRequest.AddHeader("X-Auth-Timestamp", timer.ToString()); ;
            restRequest.AddHeader("X-Auth-Version", version);


            RestClient client = new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = new Uri("https://www.bitstamp.net/")
            };

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(restRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }

        private string GetSignature(Guid nonce, string key, string secret, long timer)
        {
            string msg = $"{key}POST{_URL}{_queryParam}{_contentType}{nonce}{timer}v2{_payloadString}";
            Console.WriteLine(msg);

            return ByteArrayToString(SignHMACSHA256(secret, StringToByteArray(msg))).ToUpper();
        }
        public static byte[] SignHMACSHA256(String key, byte[] data)
        {
            HMACSHA256 hashMaker = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
            return hashMaker.ComputeHash(data);
        }

        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] hash)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Just change the XXX to your own API key and API secret, change the URL to whatever API you'd wish to access and you're good to go!

I hope it helps.
Nexigen.